# VSTO - Outlook 2007 How do I change the icon of a YesNo column in a folder view?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin, outlook-2007-addin

I have a YesNo column in a folder, and I added it to the folder view; it appears as a checked or unchecked checkbox. I've been asked to replace it with a green or red circle. Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is not possible with the OOM, I think you would need to do some WinApi to swap icons.

Comment: I thought so, but it was worth a try, I guess. Thanks anyway.